# is_dir not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, directory, dir

I've got a problem when using is_dir while I iterate over all the files in a certain directory.
The code is kind of small so I think you'll better understand what I mean if I post it:

```
 $files = array();

 if ($dir = @opendir($folder)){ 

    while($file = readdir($dir)){

      if (is_dir($file)) $files[] = $file;  
    }        
    closedir($dir);    
}
print_r($files)
```

It dumps:
( [0] => . )

Otherwise, if I don't check wether the file is a dir by using this code:

```
 $files = array();

if ($dir = @opendir($folder)){ 

    while($file = readdir($dir)){

      $files[] = $file;  
    }        
    closedir($dir);    
}
print_r($files)
```

It dumps what expected:
( [0] => .. [1] => bla [2] => blablabla [3] =>index.php [4] => styles.css [5] => . )

I guess it's just some noob problem with using the $file var as a parameter but don't know how to make it work.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: do you just want a list of all the subdirectories? if so use glob()

Comment: You appear to be reinventing the wheel for [`glob("*",GLOB_ONLYDIR)`](http://php.net/glob). If this is the case, problem has already been solved ;)

Comment: Oks, problem solved, thanks to you guys, this was pretty fast, Didn't know about this glob option nor the relative path of opendir. Thanks!!

Comment: `.` and `..` are special directories that appear automatically in EVERY directory. `.` = current directory, `..` = parent directory. Unless you filter them out, they'll always show up in opendir/readdir.

Comment: the is_dir function wants complete file/dir path as argument. Check that what you get in the $file. If you are getting only file name then you prepend the parent directory path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Kolink said in the comments, you're probably better off going the `glob` route, but if you decide to stick with opendir:

The path will be $folder . '/' . $file, not just $file. opendir() returns relative paths. So is_dir is returning false in your loop.

```
if ($dir = opendir($folder)){ 

    while(false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
            continue;
        } else if (is_dir($folder . '/' . $file)) {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }   

    closedir($dir);    

}
```

Also, note the `false !==`.  This is necessary because a folder named "0" would evaluate to false (or a few other edge cases).  Also, you'll very rarely actually care about `.` and `..`, so that code is in there to filter `.` and `..` out.

Comment: Thanks you too for answering. Already solved it, as I said in the first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is: $file contains only the basename, not the absolute filename. So prepend the path to the folder:

```
is_dir($folder . '/' . $file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<? // findfiles.php  -  what is in directory "videoarchive"
$dir    = 'images/videoarchive/'; // path from top
$files = scandir($dir);
$files_n = count($files);

echo '<br>There are '.$files_n.' records in directory '.$dir.'<br>' ;

$i=0;
while($i<=$files_n){
    // "is_dir" only works from top directory, so append the $dir before the file
    if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$files[$i])){   
        $MyFileType[$i] = "D" ; // D for Directory
    } else{
        $MyFileType[$i] = "F" ; // F for File
    }
    // print itemNo, itemType(D/F) and itemname
    echo '<br>'.$i.'. '. $MyFileType[$i].'. ' .$files[$i] ;
    $i++;
}
?>
```